# Buddypress Group creation step reordering

Tags: buddypress

If someone can help me out in changing the Steps of group creation I would really appreciate it.
The group creation steps are
1. Group details
2. Group Settings
3. Group avatar
4. Invites

Can I change this to
1. Group Details
2. Invites
3. Group Settings
4. Group avatar

please note Invite is original step 4 which I like to be on step 2. I tried playing around in bp-custom.php but dint helped.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

See function groups_action_sort_creation_steps() inside bp-groups/bp-groups-actions.php.

See **$temp** var, is an array, you can change her index. Default:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([name] => Details, [slug] => group-details),
    [10] => Array([name] => Settings, [slug] => group-settings),
    [20] => Array([name] => Avatar[slug] => group-avatar)
    [30] => Array([name] => Invites[slug] => group-invites)
)
```

Re-order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([name] => Details, [slug] => group-details),
    [10] => Array([name] => Invites[slug] => group-invites)
    [20] => Array([name] => Settings, [slug] => group-settings),
    [30] => Array([name] => Avatar[slug] => group-avatar)
)
```